# SSIS Package failed

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I am running Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition SP 2

I have created an integration package in VS 2005 which extracts data from Excel  and imports it into a table on SQL server 2005 running on this server.

The package runs ok in Visual Studio 2005,I did a bit of research which suggests this is due to SQL 64 bit and Windows 64b bit, however I am running 32 bit !!

Description: An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040154.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  H
result: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".
End Error
Error: 2010-01-04 16:02:19.14
   Code: 0xC00291EC
   Source: Delete from ExcelDB Execute SQL Task
   Description: Failed to acquire connection "Co
nnection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissio
ns on this con

Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: How are you calling the package? From a sQL agent job? Is your SQL server 64 or 32bit? If it does turn out to be a 32 vs 64 bit issue, I not so long ago had to make an SSIS package run in 32bit mode so can show you how if needed.

Comment: I am executing SSIS package from cmd(Command promt) using dtexec utility

Comment: Are you certain you are running the 32bit version? It should be the default when running from the command prompy, but you never know <drive>:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn (and sorry if I'm asking about things you've already tried)

Comment: am using exactly like this "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /f "C:\Program Files\MYSSISPackage.dtsx"

Comment: One other thought - have you checked that the excel drivers are on your server?

Comment: If you are on a 64bit server, I *think* that that is the 64bit version. Have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx

Comment: My computer has the provider, it's version 4.0.9505.0 but we are using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 in SSIS package connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions of things you could try

It says that its failing on 'Microsoft OLE DB Service Components'. Can you identify this component, and include it in a simple C#/VB.NET project. Perform a simple test within the project code, e.g. instantiate it and call a method. Then compile this to an EXE, transfer across to your server, and run it there.

The next thing to try is to trace the fault using Process Monitor:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

This is not for the faint hearted, as you could get tens of thousands of entries, but its possible to narrow the entries down:
1) Turn trace off and clear all your entries before you start.
2) Start the trace then quickly, start your package (e.g. have a command line keyed up)
3) Stop the trace as quickly as possible once you get the errors.

With any luck you might be able to determine where exactly the failure is occurring. This tool has been invaluable in the last few months, and I've followed similar step on a number of occasions.

Good luck

Comment: I can't say this is exactly the answer for this error , This Error is related to multiple mistakes like 32-bit vs 64-bit/Provider/Security, In my case it is because of connection string provider/persist security/user authentication. It is really helpfull to extend my thinking to resolve this issue